# Is there a way to know if a monster is tauntable?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

It seems to me that not every monster you fight can be taunted.

Is there a list or a way to find out in game if a monster can be taunted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing and holding on the monster brings up the ailment resistance window.

The bottom left ailment, the anger symbol on the shield is the taunt symbol. If it is invalid, it cannot be taunted:

[image]